# jQuery binding and unbinding delegate

Tags: jquery

How can i bind and unbind a `.delegate` in jquery.
Say i use this js for simple clicking.

```
function spanclick(){
    $(this).html('<input class="mm" value="' + $(this).text() + '"/>');
    $(this).unbind("click");
}
$("span.la").click(spanclick);
$("span.la").unbind("click");
```

But now i want to switch to delegate in place of simple click.
Because as of course i want to use it to selectors that have not been created on the time of page load. or do i need to use `.live()`
**Question**:
How do i `bind` and `unbind` `delegate's` in jquery ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use delegate, use `span.la` parent element (preferred) or `document` or `body`:

```
$(document).delegate('span.la', 'click', spanclick);
```

To undelegate:

```
$(document).undelegate('span.la', 'click');
```

Comment: If you're going to `.delegate()` to the `document`, you might as well use `.live()`.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Added a comment to clarify. I agree, `document` is not a good candidate.

Comment: `.delegate()` is still a little more efficient because it doesn't do a wasted initial DOM selection. Also a little better IMO because then you're thinking about event delegation, and probably more likely to be understanding what's going on.

Comment: yea i use it on a div with a id :D

Comment: @kritya: There you go then! `$('#spanContainerDiv').delegate(...)`

Comment: The one you're commenting on ;). Seriously though, mark the one that you think helped you more in undertanding what's going on.

Comment: @mrchief Ha i just didnt knew about this api. I kept on searching unbind and google kept on giving me shit :P Ill do yours to be fair because his answer got 2 and ur one so both get almost equal req :P (though u get more :P) :D :D

Answer (score 2):

use `.undelegate`

http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/