# Adding rollover effects to fancybox cusom buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I have added my own custom buttons to fancybox using the following code:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    nextEffect: 'fade',
    prevEffect: 'fade',
    closeBtn: false,
    closeClick: false,
    tpl: {
        next: '<a title="Next" class="linkbutton"><span>&#9658;</span></a>',
        prev: '<a title="Previous" class="linkbutton"><span>&#9658;</span></a>'
    },

    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    }
});
```

My 'linkbutton' class has this code bound to it:

```
$('.submitbutton, .linkbutton').bind('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: 'rgba(90,127,163,1)'},300);
});
```

Everywhere else on the site the mouseenter functionality is working just fine, but NOT where I have added it to fancybox.

How can I add the same rollover event to the fancybox custom button (to maintain site continuity/look and feel)?

Regards,

Comment: Since those are dynamically created elements, you may need to use `.bind()` in its delegated form http://stackoverflow.com/a/7059588/1055987 ..... (or use `.on()` if using jQuery v1.7+)

Answer (score 0):

This might work as a simple css solution:

```
.fancyboxt a.linkbutton {
    background-color: rgba(90,127,163,1);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 300ms linear;
    transition: background-color 300ms linear;
}
```

Comment: Mark, Good shout, but I am going to fall foul of backwards compatibility issues with older browsers...

Really looking for a javascript/JQuery solution to gracefully add the animate code to my fancybox custom button.